# D3 - use different parameters within the same JSON

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, visualization

I would like to dynamically change my bar charts using a single JSON object. My JSON looks like that:

```
[{"userID": 1, "name": "Ben", "salary": 64.0, "expenses": 10.0}, {"userID": 2, "name": "Jeff", "salary": 100.0, "expenses": 50.0}]
```

I would like to create a D3 bar chart that by selecting from a list, such as:

```
<select onchange="loadData()" id="money">
   <option >Salary</option>
   <option >Expenses</option>
</select>
```

D3 will re-create the bar chart with the relevant data. I searched for solutions, but so far they suggested i should replace my dataset. As you can see above, i'd like to stay with the same JSON and just use other fields from it.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: draw both charts at once but hide one. when the select changes, change which one is hidden

Comment: That's an interesting idea, i'll try it. Thanks!

Comment: [Here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1346410) is an example that uses the same dataset.